# fulfill deprecated - Updating to protractor 5.0.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have updated my app to protractor version 5.0.0 and I'm having an issue with `fulfill`. Take a look the code below:

```
browser.s2.util.unzip = function(report){
        return report.then(function(report){
            var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
            try {
                var zip = new AdmZip(report);
                var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); 
                zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
                    zipEntry.d =  zip.readFile(zipEntry);
                });
                defer.fulfill(zipEntries);
            } catch (err){
                defer.reject(err);
            }
            return defer;
        });
    };
```

As I saw in the [Protractor changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) they have change the **selenium-webdriver**, take a look the changelog [here](http://selenium-webdriver%20changelog). Selenium's changelog says

> Deprecated promise.fulfilled(value), use promise.Promise#resolve(value)

And I don't know what is going on with this. How should I change my code to get it working properly with protractor 5.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand it right, you can now use the [native promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (i hope it's the correct link). Like this way:

```
browser.s2.util.unzip = function(report){
    return report.then(function(report){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            try{
                // reading archives
                var zip = new AdmZip(report);
                var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records
                zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
                    zipEntry.d =  zip.readFile(zipEntry);
                });
                resolve(zipEntries);
            }catch(err){
                reject(err);
            }
        })
    });
};
```